# I don't get Lua weak tables

Tags: lua, weak-references

Okay so I want to implement a cache generator, which returns a handle to me, but doesn't give me the actual data.

```
local module = {}

cache = {}
setmetatable(cache, { __mode = "k" })

function getItem(item)
  local result = cache[item] or cacheItem(item)
  return item    
end

function cacheItem(item)
  print("Caching item")
  cache[item] = true
  return cache[item]
end

function printCache()
  for key, value in pairs(cache) do
    print(key.name .. " and " .. value)
  end
end

module.printCache = printCache
module.getItem = getItem

return module
```

But when I try to use it:

```
local module = require("./cache")

a = {
  name = "Jimmie"
}

function foo()
  local b = {
    name = "Bobbie"
  }

  local h1 = module.getCachedItem(a)
  module.getCachedItem(b)
  local h3 = module.getCachedItem({ name = "Lenny" })

  module.printCache()
end

foo()
module.printCache()
```

The first time around, I expect all names to be printed.
The second time around, I only expect "Jimmie" to be printed.
However all names are printed twice. `lua -v` returns 5.2.4.

Comment: Just insert `collectgarbage()` after calling `foo()`

Comment: Ok, wow, this actually worked. I guess Lua is pretty undeterministic in its garbage collecting behavior.

Comment: @hgiesel I don't think that's particular to Lua. I think of garbage collection as needing to run when the system runs out of pagefile space (e.g., system is disk full) and must run when the process runs out of heap space. Any sooner is to enhance process or system performance (good citizenship) and is an implementation decision that can vary from version to version, adapt to different environments, etc.